# Isolation of the transformerless power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, transformerless

[image]

One of the disadvantages of transformerless power supply is the isolation problem because of the absence of the transformer. My question here is : Doesn't the capacitor in series at the input do the trick? the capacitor is 2 parallel plates isolated from each other and the current flows through them by the electric field.
isn't that enough?

Comment: Please draw a schematic so people don't waste their time trying to understand or answering something you didn't mean. Thanks.

Comment: sorry , I have added a photo and I mean C1 at the schematic above.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens if (1) the capacitor fails short circuit or (2) the plug is inserted into the wall with the pins reversed.

Comment: ok , I get what you mean and this made me ask about something else, what is the common failure mode of the capacitor? does it depend on the "ESR" of it?

Comment: Capacitors can fail open or short circuit or anywhere in between. ESR is not relevant in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should have a capacitor for both line and neutral. Otherwise, depending on the installation/country/plug orientation/..., you'll end up with a non-isolated circuit.

Then, you should use X or Y rated capacitors for this application, to ensure safe failure mode (if it fails short, you end up with a non-isolated circuit). And I think 250V is not enough. A few thousand volts would seem better to me.

Now, honestly, even with those two requirements fulfilled, I wouldn't do that for an AC supply.

However, it can be interesting when you want to isolate two low-voltage supplies: there is even an app note from [maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4553).

Comment: Also, you should not use this for anything where the user can touch any connections (such as if it had a headphone jack, or an interface cable). This is because AC line spikes will still capacitively couple to the user relative to earth ground. This type of circuit should only be used where the device is completely *insulated*. (I have used this to run a PIC microcontroller right from AC supply.)

Comment: Good points mostly -- although the ratings on mains safety (Class X/Y) caps are working mains AC voltage, so 250VAC caps are fine.  (The safety rating tests ensure surge survivability.)

Answer (score 2):

For AC currents, the impedance of the capacitor is low. For isolation a much larger impedance is required.